# After form button is clicked, hide the button div and reveal a hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I am trying to hide the button div and reveal a hidden div after a form button has been clicked plus delay the submission/redirect. Below is what i have come up with but doesn't seem to work 100%.

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#checking').show();
  $('.button').hide();

  setTimeout(() => {}, 7000);
  return true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="details" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="CHECK" />
</form>
<div id="checking" style="display: none;">
  CHECKING DETAILS... Please wait
</div>
```

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: `setTimeout(() => {}, 7000);
  return true;` are useless

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  The question implies the former, but the empty `setTimeout` implies the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show the message and then submit, do this

```js
$('form').on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#checking').show();
  $('.button').hide();

  setTimeout(() => {
    // submit the DOM form
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); // or $("#myForm")[0].submit()
  }, 7000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="details" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="CHECK" />
</form>
<div id="checking" style="display: none;">
  CHECKING DETAILS... Please wait
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your timer callback, you need to submit the form, but when you do the `sumbit` callback will run again and again call `e.preventDefault()`, so you can use a variable as a "flag" to check as to whether you should cancel the event or not.

```js
let flag = false;

$('form').on("submit", function(e) {
  if(!flag){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#checking').show();
    $('.button').hide();
    flag = true;
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('form').submit();
  }, 7000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://www.example.com" method="Post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="details" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="CHECK" />
</form>
<div id="checking" style="display: none;">
  CHECKING DETAILS... Please wait
</div>
```